# MySQL Fulltext search but using LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm recently doing some string searches from a table with about 50k strings in it, fairly large I'd say but not that big. I was doing some nested queries for a 'search within results' kinda thing. I was using LIKE statement to get a match of a searched keyword.

I came across MySQL's Full-Text search which I tried so I added a fulltext index to my `str` column. I'm aware that Full-text searches doesn't work on virtually created tables or even with `Views` so queries with sub-selects will not fit. I mentioned I was doing a nested queries, example is:

```
SELECT s2.id, s2.str 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT s1.id, s1.str 
    FROM 
        (
         SELECT id, str 
         FROM strings 
         WHERE str LIKE '%term%'
         ) AS s1 
    WHERE s1.str LIKE '%another_term%'
    ) AS s2 
WHERE s2.str LIKE '%a_much_deeper_term%';
```

This is actually not applied to any code yet, I was just doing some tests. Also, searching strings like this can be easily achieved by using Sphinx (performance wise) but let's consider Sphinx not being available and I want to know how this will work well in pure SQL query. Running this query on a table without Full-text added takes about `2.97 secs`. (depends on the search term). However, running this query on a table with Full-text added to the `str` column finished in like 104ms which is fast (i think?).

My question is simple, is it valid to use **LIKE** or is it a good practice to use it at all in a table with Full-text added when normally we would use **MATCH** and **AGAINST** statements?

Thanks!

Comment: You can always use fulltext index in the **innermost** query of the nester SQL's. Of course this depends on the fact whether you are searching for **wole words**.

Comment: @vbence awesome, i just tried that on the innermost query the result is finished in like 15ms. this is in my localhost btw, but it's even more faster replacing WHERE str LIKE '%term%' to WHERE MATCH(str) AGAINST('term') :)

Comment: The big question is, are you only searching for full words?

Comment: @vbence nope, string occurance with strings. But you're right if it's a full word search it's good to use fullindex on the innermost part. Thanks for reminding that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you not neccessarily need subselects. You can siply use:

```
SELECT id, str
FROM item_strings
WHERE str LIKE '%term%'
   AND str LIKE '%another_term%'
   AND str LIKE '%a_much_deeper_term%'
```

... but also raises a good question: the order in which you are excluding the rows. I guess MySQL is smart enough to assume that the longest term will be the most restrictive, so starting with `a_much_deeper_term` it will eliminate most of the records then perform addtitional comparsion only on a few rows. - Contrary to this, if you start with `term` you will probably end up with many possible records then you have to compare them against the st of the terms.

The interesting part is that you can force the order in which the comparsion is made by using your original *subselect* example. This gives the opportunity to make a decision which term is the most restrictive based upon more han just the length, but for example:

- the ratio of consonants a vowels
- the longest chain of consonants of the word
- the most used vowel in the word

...etc. You can also apply some *heuristics* based on the type of textual infomation you are handling.

**Edit:**

This is just a hunch but it could be possible to apply the `LIKE` to the `words` in the fulltext indexitself. Then match the rows against the index as if you have serched for full words.

I'm not sure if this is actually done, but it would be a smart thing to pull off by the MySQL people. Also note that this theory can only be used if all possible ocurrences arein fact in the fulltext search. For this you need that:

- Your search pattern must be at least the size of the miimal word-length. (If you re searching for example `%id%` then it can be a part of a 3 letter word too, which is excluded by default form FULLTEXT index).
- Your search pattern must not be a substring of any listed excluded word for example: and, of etc.
- Your pattern must not contain any special characters.

Comment: Interesting, I guess I'm making it complicated by the sub-selects I had when it can be achieved by a single query and you hit the mark by having it, it forces the order of comparison in a strict manner. I tried it and doesn't make much a difference in terms of speed. Question now is, when a table is applied with Fulltext index, is using **LIKE** valid and **proper** as if the table is just indexed to make it fast?

Comment: @tradyblix I added a new thought to my answer concerning `LIKE` and `FULLTEXT`.

Comment: Got it, so in theory it is possible but there are obviously some things to keep in mind in which may affect the search. Thanks for  pointing that out, those 3 things you mentioned are things I never thought of in case of the FULLTEXT index and by using LIKE with it. It is likely that if I may want to use LIKE, I guess I need to make sure that some things are considered first. I'm satisfied.